# Get X and Y position after searching an element in a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having troubles thinking a solution to this problem.

I have this [table](https://jsfiddle.net/66bmk4qm/) and a JSON like this one:

```
{:id=>"e-123",
 :subject_initials=>"IN",
 :grade=>"12"}
```

I need to search on the table the id of the person (which in this case is "e-123") and search on the first row the initials of the subject and put the grade on the X and Y position.

The result of the example above should be something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/66bmk4qm/1/)

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. so please elaborate more. what do you mean  by `and put the grade on the X and Y position.`?

Comment: The second link I put is the end goal, after getting the row where the person id matches i need to search the column of the subject initials and in that row put the grade, the two links have the exact example that what i need to do, look the first row and the second column, on the first example there was an "*" and on the second example that changed for the "grade" value of the json "12" @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to search through the heading inputs to get a column index and search through the user id inputs to get a row index then use `eq()` method to isolate the one you need to update

```
var $subjectInput = $('tr').first().find('input').filter(function() {
  return this.value === data.subject_initials
});

var $idInput = $('tr').find('td:eq(1) input').filter(function() {
  return this.value.toLowerCase() === data.id
});

var colIdx = $subjectInput.parent('td').index();
var rowIdx = $idInput.closest('tr').index();

$('tr').eq(rowIdx).find('td').eq(colIdx).find('input').val(data.grade)
```

Adding some additional classes on these 2 types of inputs would help make the selectors for finding them easier

---

If the rows are generated dynamically adding an ID to the row and course name class to the data entry inputs you could simplify the whole thing immensely

```
<tr id="e-123">
    .....
      <input class="form-control course_IN">
```

JS

```
 $('#' + data.id).find('input.course_' + data.subject_initials).val(data.grade)
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/66bmk4qm/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much Charlie, you saved my life I was going crazy thinking about this hahaha, you're the best!